# C, card game WAR

Tags: c

I am trying to create a War card game using C. Instead of making 2 decks for the "discarded" cards to be added to a players hand at a later time, I am instead just trying to add the dealers card[i] - which was previously compared with players card[i] to ensure that the player won the hand - to the players hand directly. index is used to make sure there are no empty elements playerhand ever points to by appending another card on to the end of the “hand,” which initially has 26 cards (half the deck). the deck is initially split in 2, the first 26 cards deck[0-25] going to the player's hand, and the last 26 deck[26-51] going to the dealers hand.

here is my code in question:

```
    //adds new card to deck at given index
void addToPlayerHand(int i) {
    int index=0;
    playerHand[index+26] = deck[i+26];
    index++;
    }
```

here is my full game code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Type Stucture for Card
typedef struct cards {
    char suit;
    int face;
    struct cards *listp; // didn't use in this program
} card;

//Functions
//
int welcome();
//int checkWinWar();
int playGame();

int getComparison(card *firstCard,card *secndCard,int index);


void printingGame(int a,int b, int i);
void addToPlayerHand(int i);
void addToDealerHand(int i);
int addToDeck(card myCards, int index);
void hitPlayer(card theCard);
void hitDealer(card theCard);
void initilizeDeck();
int shuffleDeck();
int printFun(); // not used for game play

void freePlayers();


//Card Dynamics
//
card *playerHand;  // contains contents of players cards
card *dealerHand; // contains contents of dealers cards

//Deck of 52 Cards with discard decks
card deck[52];
card playerDeck[52];
card dealerDeck[52];

int numPlayer = 0;
int numAllPlayer = 0;

int numDealer = 0;  // needed for temp
int numAllDealer = 0;




//Main
int main(void) {


    printf("Hello..Welcome to WAR\n");



    //Game loop
    while (welcome() == 1) {  // welcome returns whether the player wants to play (1) or not (0)

        // put first card face up
        // display how many cards
        // indicate (if/if no) war has occurred
        // complete the war
        // add cards to player discard pile
        // check player for card count
        // if end game conition met, end hame


        if(playGame() == 1) { // playGame returns 1 if the function went through correctly

            if(checkWinWar()==1){

            }
            else{

            }

        } else {
            printf("Bust! Try Again\n\n");
            freePlayers(); // refreshes the dynamics of the hands
        }

    }



    //initilizeDeck();
    //shuffleDeck();
    //printFun();

    return 0;
}

//To allow the player to begin the game; 1 = True 0 = False
int welcome() {

    printf("Play a new round of WAR? (enter/return for yes):\t");

    if(getchar()=='\n'){
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;


}

// refreshes the game and players
void freePlayers () {

    numDealer = 0;
    numPlayer = 0;

    numAllPlayer = 0;
    numAllDealer = 0;

    free(playerHand);
    free(dealerHand);

    playerHand = NULL; // needed so playerHand doesn't point to anything
    dealerHand = NULL;

    return;
}


// Playing of the game
int playGame() {

    initilizeDeck();  // initialize Deck returns the new deck of cards
    shuffleDeck();  // shuffleDeck returns the shuffled deck of cards

    int gameTrue = 1;  // gameTrue checks the state of the game

    int war = 0;
    int PlayerCardsRemaining=0;
    int DealerCardsRemaining=0;

    int temp,i,j=0;

    while (gameTrue == 1) {
        // splitting the deck
        for (j=0;j<26;j++){
            hitPlayer(deck[j]); // adding cards to playerHand
            PlayerCardsRemaining+=1;  //adding to player deck count.
        }
        for (j=26;j<52;j++){
            hitDealer(deck[j]);
            DealerCardsRemaining+=1;}  // adding to dealer deck count.



        i=0;
        while(PlayerCardsRemaining>0 && DealerCardsRemaining>0 && i<26) {

            printingGame(DealerCardsRemaining,PlayerCardsRemaining, i);

            if (getComparison(playerHand, dealerHand, i)==0){
                addToDealerHand(i);
                DealerCardsRemaining++;
                return 1;
            }
            else if(getComparison(playerHand,dealerHand,i)==1){
                addToPlayerHand(i);
                PlayerCardsRemaining++;
                return 1;
            }
            else if(getComparison(playerHand, dealerHand, i)==2){
                printf("There is an impending WAR\n");
                printf("press enter to engage in the WAR");
                war=1;



                if(war==1 && DealerCardsRemaining>=4 && PlayerCardsRemaining>=4){
                    temp=getComparison(playerHand, dealerHand, i+4);

                    while(war==1){

                        if(temp==0){
                            for(i=i;i<i+4;i++){
                                addToDealerHand(i);
                            }
                            war=0;
                            PlayerCardsRemaining-=4;
                            DealerCardsRemaining+=4;
                        }
                        else if(temp==1){
                            for(i=i;i<i+4;i++){
                                addToPlayerHand(i);
                            }
                            war=0;
                            DealerCardsRemaining-=4;
                            PlayerCardsRemaining+=4;
                        }
                        else
                            war=1;
                    }
                return 1;
                }
                if (DealerCardsRemaining<<4){
                    for(i=i;i<i+4;i++){
                        addToPlayerHand(i);
                    }
                }
                else if (PlayerCardsRemaining<<4){
                    for(i=i;i<i+4;i++){
                        addToDealerHand(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            i++; // increment i

        }


    }
    return 0;
}

void printingGame(int DealerCardsRemaining, int PlayerCardsRemaining, int i)
{
    // Gameplay Prompts

    //Prints interface that comes up after player(s) choose to play
    printf("*********\t\t*********\n");
    printf("*\t \t*\t\t*\t \t*\n");

    // Cases for cards that are face cards

    if(dealerHand[i].face==11){ // if dealer card is a jack
        printf("*\tJ\t*\t\t");
        if (playerHand[i].face<11){ // if player card isnt a face card
            printf("*\t%d\t*\n",playerHand[i].face);
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==11){ // if player card is a face card
            printf("*\tJ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==12){
            printf("*\tQ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==13){
            printf("*\tK\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==14){
            printf("*\tA\t*\n");
        }
    }
    else if(dealerHand[i].face==12){ // if dealer card is a queen
        printf("*\tQ\t*\t\t");
        if (playerHand[i].face<11){ // if player card isnt a face card
            printf("*\t%d\t*\n",playerHand[0].face);
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==11){ // if player card is a face card
            printf("*\tJ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==12){
            printf("*\tQ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==13){
            printf("*\tK\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==14){
            printf("*\tA\t*\n");
        }
    }
    else if(dealerHand[i].face==13){ // if dealer card is a king
        printf("*\tK\t*\t\t");
        if (playerHand[i].face<11){ // if player card isnt a face card
            printf("*\t%d\t*\n",playerHand[i].face);
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==11){ // if player card is a face card
            printf("*\tJ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==12){
            printf("*\tQ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==13){
            printf("*\tK\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==14){
            printf("*\tA\t*\n");
        }
    }
    else if(dealerHand[i].face==14){ // if dealer card is an ace
        printf("*\tA\t*\t\t");
        if (playerHand[i].face<11){ // if player card isnt a face card
            printf("*\t%d\t*\n",playerHand[i].face);
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==11){ // if player card is a face card
            printf("*\tJ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==12){
            printf("*\tQ\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==13){
            printf("*\tK\t*\n");
        }
        else if(playerHand[i].face==14){
            printf("*\tA\t*\n");
        }
    }
    if (dealerHand[i].face<11 && playerHand[i].face<11){ // if both cards arent face cards
        printf("*\t%d\t*\t\t*\t%d\t*\n",dealerHand[i].face,playerHand[i].face);
    }
    printf("*\t \t*\t\t*\t \t*\n");
    printf("*********\t\t*********\n");
    printf("Dealer: %d cards. ",DealerCardsRemaining); // print how many cards the 'dealer' has
    printf("Player: %d cards. ",PlayerCardsRemaining); // print how many cards the player  has

}


int getComparison (card *firstCard, card *secndCard, int i)
{
    int a,b;
    a=firstCard[i].face;
    b=secndCard[i].face;
    if (b>a)
        return 0;
    else if (a>b)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}

// gives player another card
void hitPlayer (card theCard) {
    if(numPlayer == 0) {  // if hitPlayer is giving playerHand its first card (for new deck or initial deck)

        if (numAllPlayer == 0)      // if its the first hand
            numAllPlayer = 1; // there is only one card in need of space
        else                        // if its not the first hand
            numAllPlayer++;   // you need space for all existing cards plus the one just added

        void *_tmp = realloc(playerHand, (numAllPlayer * sizeof(card))); // realloc is used since playerHand never has a constant size

        if (!_tmp) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Couldn't realloc memory!\n"); // stderr prints
        }
        playerHand = (card*)_tmp; // playerHand is card type pointer which points to void pointer tmp which is reallocating memory
    }
    playerHand[numPlayer] = theCard;
    numPlayer++;
}

// gives dealer another card
void hitDealer (card theCard) {
    if(numDealer == 0) {

        if (numAllDealer == 0)
            numAllDealer = 1;
        else
            numAllDealer++;

        void *_tmp = realloc(dealerHand, (numAllDealer * sizeof(card)));

        if (!_tmp)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Couldn't realloc memory!\n");
        }
        dealerHand = (card*)_tmp;
    }
    dealerHand[numDealer] = theCard;
    numDealer++;
}

// creates a new deck of cards
void initilizeDeck() {

    //Loop Indexes like: count, i.... etc
    int i, p;

    int count = 0;
    card temp;

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        for (p = 2; p <= 14; p++) {
            //Clubs
            if (i == 1) {
                temp.suit = 'C';
                temp.face = p;
            }
            //Diamonds
            if (i == 2) {
                temp.suit = 'D';
                temp.face = p;
            }
            //Hearts
            if (i == 3) {
                temp.suit = 'H';
                temp.face = p;
            }
            //Spades
            if (i == 4) {
                temp.suit = 'S';
                temp.face = p;
            }
            addToDeck(temp, count);
            count++;
        }
    }
}

//adds new card to deck at given index
int addToDeck(card myCards, int index) {
    deck[index] = myCards;
    return 1;
}
//adds new card to deck at given index
void addToPlayerHand(int i) {
    int index=0;
    playerHand[index+26] = deck[i+26];
    index++;
    }
//adds new card to deck at given index
void addToDealerHand(int i) {
    int index=0;
    dealerHand[index+26] = deck[i];
    index++;
}


//finds deck and shuffles cards 100 times from swaping a random value from  1-52
int shuffleDeck() {

    card temp;  // for an individual card

    int i,p;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (p = 0; p < 52; p++) {
            int r = rand()%52;

            temp = deck[p];  // swaps to randomly pick another card
            deck[p] = deck[r];
            deck[r] = temp;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

it keeps telling me i have a bad access code, code=2.

any help would be awesome.

Comment: I'm quite-certain that is not *all* your code. Posting the declarations of both `playerHand[]` and `deck[]` will speak volumes in finding your problem. Seeing how `i` is controlled when passed to this function will be equally helpful.

Comment: ill just post my whole code

Comment: Excellent. If you can squeeze the problem down to less than a hundred lines and *update the question* (don't try to post it in a comment) that would be terrific.

Comment: You have `if(checkWinWar()==1)` but not `checkWinWar` function in this code. Also these `for` loop conditions are wrong `for(i=i;i<i+4;i++)` not clear what you intended.

Comment: Shafik-
youre correct, im currently trying to write checkWinWar but in the code it doesnt reflect that
also, the for loop that increments 4 times is supposed to give 4 cards to the winner of the war, due to the fact that a war calls for 3 "buried" cards and one card face up to compare to the other player.

Comment: @WheezyTrees So if I understand then that is not the error you are seeing? If so can you provide the exact error and the line number you are seeing the error on?

Comment: yes - the error is a BAD_ACCESS_CODE error, and it is located in the "code in question" block above the main code

Answer (score 2):

I'll dispense with the "I'd never code this that way" dialogue long enough to suggest that this loop ideology:

```
for(i=i;i<i+4;i++)
```

will look well past the limits of your card arrays and into the land of **undefined behavior**. Think about it a minute. Then ask yourself this question: At what point will `i` no longer be less than `i+4` ? Answer: when you reach the point when `i+4` overflows to become negative (assuming the optimizer doesn't throw out the condition entirely and just assume it is always true; thanks Jeremy).

I.e. `INT_MAX-3`. On a 32-bit system that is only about 2147483562 slots **past** the end of your array.

This error is repeated 3 more times in the `playGame()` function.

Comment: You allude to undefined behaviour. To expand on that point: it is legitimate for the compiler to conclude that `i<i+4` is always true and optimize it out. This is because what happens when you overflow a signed integer is actually undefined, so the compiler can assume that the condition will hold in that case, and thus always.